# Why am I getting a Blank Page but React is compiling successfully?

Tags: reactjs, class, components, jsx

I don't understand why I get a blank page when I run npm start. I am trying to have the  and

tags to render.

Here is the code:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import Card from './Card';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'tachyons';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Card />
  </React.StrictMode>
  ,

  document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Card.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = (_props) => {
    return  (
        <div>
            <img alt='robots' src='' />
            <div>
                <h2>Jane Doe</h2>
                <p>janedoe@gmail.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

I have followed several pieces of advice from fellow students in my class who were experiencing similar issues however none of them seems quite to apply to my code, as I haven't found similar typos or other documentation or syntax issues.

Comment: Can you share the version of react you are using or include your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; use this!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using an newer version of react and the notation has changed a bit.

newer versions of create use the createRoot Method.

Here is the completed example

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import Card from './card';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Card />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```